# Why doesn't the LaunchScreen.xib work for my iPhone 4 during app launch?

Tags: xcode

I create a launch screen xib file from xCode 6.1.1 to use as a launch screen and it works fine when I launch the app from my iPhone 6. However, the launch screen is black for my iPhone 4.

I followed suggestions online to "Use Asset Catalog" for Launch Image Source as well as "LaunchScreen" for Launch Screen File.

There are no images for LaunchImage file in Images.xcassets image.

What steps am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: LaunchScreen.xib is iOS 8 feature. iOS 8 does not run on an iPhone 4.

Comment: I'm an idiot!...I knew that, but for some reason, I wanted to not believe it :D ... Does that mean I need to provide a launch image file to support the iPhone 4 and iPhone 3Gs resolution? thanks matt

Comment: Yes I think you can just use the old-fashioned _Default.png_ files like we used to do... You will have to experiment, I have not tried combining that with a Launch Screen.

Comment: thanks, how can I accept your answer?

Comment: @Pangu Sorry for bringing up an old answer, but create an answer with matt's answer and accept it.